# How do I change this exif data into long and lat?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, image, linux

I've been using ImageMagick in a Linux terminal but I'm not sure how to read the coordinates it's giving me.
[image]

If you can't see the picture, the data is:

```
Properties:
    date:create: 2020-05-21T12:33:53+01:00
    date:modify: 2020-05-21T12:33:53+01:00
    exif:ExifOffset: 38
    exif:GPSDateStamp: 2015:12:09
    exif:GPSInfo: 68
    exif:GPSLatitude: 23/1, 21/1, 35928/625
    exif:GPSLatitudeRef: N
    exif:GPSLongitude: 98/1, 0/1, 14886/625
    exif:GPSLongitudeRef: W
    exif:GPSMapDatum: WGS-84
    exif:GPSTimeStamp: 11/1, 21/1, 42/1
    exif:GPSVersionID: 2, 2, 0, 0
    exif:PixelXDimension: 1000
    exif:PixelYDimension: 660
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: 1c3ce39629e01d4cf738f153e810a468264c1dc110a9af7ebe37b83e81969ee3
    xmp:GPSLatitude: 23,21.958080N
    xmp:GPSLongitude: 98,0.396960E
    xmp:GPSMapDatum: WGS-84
    xmp:GPSTimeStamp: 2015-12-09T11:21:42.37Z
    xmp:GPSVersionID: 2.2.0.0
    xmp:PixelXDimension: 1000
    xmp:PixelYDimension: 660
```

Comment: would recommend exiftools [linux] sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl https://exiftool.org/

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates are clearly spelled out in your screen capture.

Latitude = 23° 21.958080N in DD MM:MM (3/1, 21/1, 35928/625 is this same value in DMS) or -23.365968° in Decimal Degrees

Longitude = 98° 0.396960E in DD MM:MM (98/1, 0/1, 14886/625 is this same value in DMS) or 98.023283° in Decimal Degrees.

Your reference system is WGS 1984

You have 1000 pixels in the X dimension (Longitude)

You have 660 pixels in the Y dimension (Longitude)

Answer (score 2):

I see that ImageMagik is giving you the coordinates as degrees with decimal minutes in the XMP header.  The coordinates are also being stored in the EXIF header.  You just need to do the division to get the values.
23/1, 21/1, 35928/625 = 23 degrees, 21 minutes, 57.4848 seconds north